# How include JSON data in local brunch app

Tags: json, pug, local, offline, brunch

I'm not much of a web developer yet. I want to create a local (yes, really offline) html/js (coffeescript/jade) app, using brunch.
I would like to have some JSON files with data like

```
{
  "title": "My title",
  "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor..."
}
```

Now this data should be included in the app. I created a mixin:

```
mixin test_block(data)
  h1 data.title
  p data.content
```

How can I achieve this to keep the data separated from the mixin/jade code?
The reason for this is: I don't need/want a db or aclient/server approach. I just want a completely local 5-pages-webpage, compiled into html and very few js. It must be placeable on a USB stick and run by clicking on the index.html.

I want to add new content by e.g. adding a new json file (e.g. `welcome.json`) and placing a new mixin call into the jade file ( `test_block(welcome)`)
Brunch does a nice job compiling/concatenating all the stuff into very few files. Bit I don't get how to fetch the data out of the json files.

Is there a better approach? Maybe the JSON thing is not the best one.
But this content needs to be generated by other people, programmatically, from a database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone a hint? I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer to anyone who need it:
As far as I found out, it is **not** possible without using an e.g. backbone model. I ended using jade as wrapper:

```
personA = { firstname: "Tom", lastname: "Jones" }
```

and including that in another jade file